# Element's background color could not be determined because it is overlapped by another element

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I am trying to create an accessible switch element but my accessibility report says `Elements must have sufficient color contrast` with the reason mentioned as `Element's background color could not be determined because it is overlapped by another element` for label element. I am still learning the accessibility aspect so I don't have much idea why I am getting this warning. I tried using pseudo-element instead of `span`, changing `z-index` for `label`, adding background color with high contrast but nothing seems to help. What am I missing here

```css
.switch {
  --handle-width: 30px;
  --transition-duration: 250ms;
  --handle-transition: all var(--transition-duration) ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  gap: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch--checkbox {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
}

.switch--handle {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(2 * var(--handle-width));
  height: var(--handle-width);
  border-radius: var(--handle-width);
  background-color: hsl(5, 76%, 95%);
  border: 1px solid hsl(5, 76%, 85%);
  transition: var(--handle-transition);
}

.switch--handle-ball {
  position: absolute;
  --offset: 2px;
  top: var(--offset);
  left: var(--offset);
  height: calc(var(--handle-width) - 2 * var(--offset));
  width: calc(var(--handle-width) - var(--offset));
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: hsl(346, 66%, 100%);
  transition: var(--handle-transition);
}

.switch--checkbox:checked+.switch--handle {
  background-color: hsl(129, 60%, 85%);
  border-color: hsl(129, 60%, 85%);
}

.switch--checkbox:checked~.switch--handle-ball {
  left: var(--handle-width);
  background-color: hsl(346, 66%, 100%);
}
```

```html
<label for="switch-input" class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="switch-input" class="switch--checkbox" />
      <div class="switch--handle" hidden></div>
      Send notification
      <span class="switch--handle-ball" />
    </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the accessibility values of the colors of your site. That color for your `false` state is a very light pink... can't really tell. When I use an accessibility tester (i.e.; webaim.org), it will return a contrast ratio.

When I entered the hsl color for your `false` state switch, it returns the following results: https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=F6C1BC&bcolor=FFFFFF.

[image]

From within that tool, you can play around with the color scheme until you get your colors where you need them. There are colorblind people that use the web and some of the colors they typically can't see are red and green.

Here's another resource you can use that explains colorblindness testing:

https://css-tricks.com/accessibility-basics-testing-your-page-for-color-blindness/

Comment: I did try with other colors, for eg, I used #6246ea for the background for `switch--handle` but it doesn't work. `Element's background color could not be determined because it is overlapped by another element` seems to suggest since we are overlapping label element with other elements by virtue of using absolute position,  could contribute to this issue

Comment: Where are you seeing that message? Are you using Lighthouse or another testing tool?

Comment: I am using both use axe con chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe-devtools-web-accessib/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd or storybook with accessibility plugin

Answer (score 0):

Just manually check the contrast ratio, Reference Site: https://contrast-ratio.com/

Manually entered the background color and color of the text used. Sometimes, the axe Devtool of the chrome extension didn't recognize and throws an error, which in actual is not an error.

Hope this could help.